# Не получается отправить сообщение на mail!

Tags: android

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("message/rfc822");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"GGGG@gmail.ru"});
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body of email");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail..."));
```

В итоге открывается ВК и спрашивает на стену или в сообщение отправить, фигня какая - то

Comment: А поподробней можно?

Comment: ну так а может элементарно нет почтового клиента

Comment: почтовый клиент то есть хоть один?)

Comment: Конечно есть)). Вы же пользуетесь андроидом, там стандартный всегда во всех осях андроида есть), тот же самый Google mail

Comment: и на Genymotion?)

Comment: @ermak0ff, Вон он наверху)

Comment: @xTIGRx убедил) просто помниться ранее в gm стандартно не было google-сервисов

Comment: @ermak0ff, Может все таки мой код корявый? или чего - то не хватает, в манифесте ничего не писал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, Uri.fromParts(
            "mailto","GGGG@gmail.ru", null));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```

Дело в том, что обработчик Intent'а `ACTION_SEND` для того, чтобы понять кому, сначала парсит приложенный `Uri` и если его нет то пытается ветвиться по mime типу предложенному в `setType()`. Если вы подсунете ему `Uri` на тип `mailto:`, то он выдаст список ваших почтовых клиентов.

Comment: Выше скинул картинку, такую ранее получал, думаете все дело в эмуляторе?

Comment: Да, это характерно для эмулятора, хотя GenyMotion вроде поддерживает email агента...

Comment: на реальном телефоне тоже самое o_O

Comment: Ваш код вообще не работает. Короче проверил на своем телефоне свой код, там все работает, и даже майл в выборе появился

Comment: Попробуй `Intent.ACTION_SENDTO`